# BanksClient: should I prefer `process_transaction_with_metadata` over `process_transaction?`

Tags: rust, testing, program-test, solana-program-test

I've noticed that `process_transaction` (and `process_transaction_with_preflight_and_commitment`) hangs when a program is missing from BanksServer or when it encounters an AccountInUse error. It probably hangs in other places too.

Meanwhile `process_transaction_with_metadata` does not hang in these situations, but instead returns a `BanksTransactionResultWithMetadata` that contains the error information.

Hanging sucks, so is it a good idea to just always use `process_transaction_with_metadata`?

Comment: Yeah probably. The implementations work very different, since `process_transaction` executes the transaction async by sending the transaction and waiting to see a notification, whereas `process_transaction_with_metadata` executes the transaction directly on the bank. On the flipside, it might be better to isolate the bugs on the client and server so that it works properly

Comment: Cool. I'm adding program-test support to solders and I think I'll use `process_transaction_with_metadata` under the hood instead of `process_transaction` since I don't want a bunch of kids shooting themselves in the foot

Comment: Ooooh that's exciting! `process_transaction_with_metadata` will give you more flexibility, but we'll fix `process_transaction` on the sooner side (I hope)

Comment: Thanks for the colour! The ProgramTest wrapper is now available under solders.bankrun https://kevinheavey.github.io/solders/tutorials/bankrun.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, I think the subjective answer to my question looks like "yes, but hopefully `process_transaction` gets fixed soon too".